# Preventing single quotes being escaped in image_tag onClick in .ERB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I have this line of code in my ERB file:

```
<% image_tag("foo.png", :onClick => "do_x('param')") %>
```

This produces the bad HTML:

```
<img src="/assets/foo.png" onClick="do_x(&#27;param&#27;)" />
```

I've tried using:

```
<% raw image_tag("foo.png", :onClick => "do_x('param')") %>
```

But that makes no difference. I'm running Rails 3.2.14.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try use `<%= image_tag("foo.png", :onClick => "do_x('param')".html_safe ) %>`.

Because your string include quotes that will be transferred default :)